# Adding new entries in LDAP server using angular 4 app

Tags: angular, openldap

I have to add new users to ldap (I am using OpenLdap as server). What node module can be used to accomplish this using angular app ? Any example is highly appreciated. I am using angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`LDAP` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/LDAP).

Be sure to read how to install it properly.

This is a brief example of its usage to add a person:

```
var attrs = [
    { attr: 'objectClass',  vals: [ 'organizationalPerson', 'person', 'top' ] },
    { attr: 'sn',           vals: [ 'Smith' ] },
    { attr: 'badattr',      vals: [ 'Fried' ] }
]

ldap.add(dn, attrs, function(err));
```